# 8x16 GB on an X99 motherboard with i7-5930k

Tags: memory, cpu, motherboard, gpu, storage

I have a computer with ASUS motherboard all series motherboard x99-a. I want to upgrade it, from 64GB of ram (8x8GB) to 128GB of RAM (8x16GB).

Multiple sources say that the max ram for is 64GB (including ark.intel). However, I tried (8x16GB) and it worked and the system detected it, but I am worried I can't make full use of the portion of RAM above 64GB because of what I've found.

**The question**
Can I use 8x16GB in my configuration without issues?

Here is the specs:

[image]

Comment: Read the rules. We don't recommend hardware here.

Comment: @music2myear I am not asking for type of hardware, I am asking for capabilities

Comment: According to Intel - https://ark.intel.com/content/www/us/en/ark/products/82931/intel-core-i7-5930k-processor-15m-cache-up-to-3-70-ghz.html - your CPU can't handle more then 64 gigs, regardless of the motherboard.  If you don't already have one, an SSD will usually make a big difference to performance. A GPU might, depending on your use case.

Comment: I think it actually just works, and Intel is wrong in this case. If you have the RAM to test, I would just install it and run an extensive memtest to be sure. You might've already found: https://www.techpowerup.com/forums/threads/128gb-ram-on-x99-platform-with-5820k-no-problem.222305/

Comment: @Tak I think music2myear is referring to this part of your question: "I wonder what is the best options advice and recommendations if I wanted to max out this machine in terms of Fast storage, memory, CPU and GPU. ". I would suggest you remove that, as that part is indeed against the rules and it detracts from your otherwise valid question.